# Password validation code not passing every random test, do not understand why?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, validation

I am new to coding/programming, and have been trying to just solve as many problems as i can on codewars.com

I came across the following regex pw validation problem
https://www.codewars.com/kata/regex-password-validation/train/javascript

You need to write regex that will validate a password to make sure it meets the following criteria:

At least six characters long
contains a lowercase letter
contains an uppercase letter
contains a number
Valid passwords will only be alphanumeric characters.

Here is my code

```
function validate(password){
  return (/(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.{6,}).*/g.test(password));
}
```

I pass all of the sample tests, and most of the random tests, but there are two i keep failing. I have no way of seeing the input, so I do not know why it is that I am failing. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated :)

Comment: What are the tests that fail?

Comment: when I click on the attempt button, it is the 7th and 8th tests. I know you are asking for the strings that fail, but unfortunately I cannot see them. It just says that I failed (or passed) the tests.

Comment: Remove the `g` flag.

Comment: Hi, why would it be better to remove the g flag?

Comment: What tests do fail? - Not ALL characters are allowed in passwords - this regex tests upper/lower case, numbers and(?=.{6,}) catches (/_.\? etc...) and sets 6 char minimum - you can check your REGEX with https://regex101.com/

Comment: @user1213320 For some reason I could not see the input for the tests I was failing, which is why I eventually posted here.  My code was allowing non alphanumeric characters, that was my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not following this rule:

> Valid passwords will only be alphanumeric characters

You're allowing them to contain any characters as long as the other rules pass. Change the `.*` at the end to `^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$` to make sure that every character is alphanumeric.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, I passed the tests. would you mind please explaining why I was failing? What kind of characters are not considered alpha numeric in JS? Does the ^  mean?

Comment: @Y.D Your regex would accept `Test123#` where `#` is not an alphanumeric character.

Comment: @Ivar Thank you for the clarification, I've been trying to solve that problem for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

I see one problem with your Regex: It allows `any` characters to be in the password (after it has checked that there's one lowercase, one uppcase and one number).
Without knowing why the tests fail, we can at least fix this issue:

```
function validate(password){
  return (/(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}*/.test(password));
}
```

Comment: Good question, I copied from the question, have edited now.

Comment: thank you for your answer, that was indeed the issue.